# How do I increase the speed of my USB cdc device?

Tags: c, embedded, bare-metal

I am upgrading the processor in an embedded system for work. This is all in C, with no OS. Part of that upgrade includes migrating the processor-PC communications interface from IEEE-488 to USB. I finally got the USB firmware written, and have been testing it. It was going great until I tried to push through lots of data only to discover my USB connection is slower than the old IEEE-488 connection. I have the USB device enumerating as a CDC device with a baud rate of 115200 bps, but it is clear that I am not even reaching that throughput, and I thought that number was a dummy value that is a holdover from RS232 days, but I might be wrong. I control every aspect of this from the front end on the PC to the firmware on the embedded system.

I am assuming my issue is how I write to the USB on the embedded system side. Right now my USB_Write function is run in free time, and is just a while loop that writes one char to the USB port until the write buffer is empty. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

One of my concerns that I have, is that in the old system we had a board in the system dedicated to communications. The CPU would just write data across a bus to this board, and it would handle communications, which means that the CPU didn't have to waste free time handling the actual communications, but could offload the communications to a "co processor" (not a CPU but functionally the same here). Even with this concern though I figured I should be getting faster speeds given that full speed USB is on the order of MB/s while IEEE-488 is on the order of kB/s.

In short is this more likely a fundamental system constraint or a software optimization issue?

Comment: understand where your performance problem is, it could be as simple as the command line options used for the compiler or the library you are using.

Comment: your processor/chip should be doing most of the heavy lifting of the usb protocol you should only be dealing with the packets if you will, a data structure lands you look at it respond, repeat forever.  some the hardware does even more of the work.

Comment: USB speeds rely heavily on exchanging complete buffers. If you only send one byte per whatever buffer size you chose (16, 32 bytes are typical) then you will waste a lot of performance.

People can help you more if you post the processor name/link to datasheet. Also read up whether this is a full-speed or high-speed device. Also tell us the speeds you currently achieve. Full-speed has a maximum of 64 byte per frame with frames spaced at 1 ms intervals: ~1 kB/s if you only send one byte per frame.

Comment: K64f

http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/data-sheets/K64P144M120SF5.pdf

Comment: If you can transfer single bytes already, then your basic buffer descriptor setup seems to work. What's keeping you from filling the buffers and then sending them out?

Comment: Nothing, I was thinking too much in terms of RS232 protocols when I wrote the code. If it's not obvious this is my first rodeo with USB, and dear god it is complex. I gueess that is the price for being so versatile.

Comment: The baud rate should be irrelevant; that is signalled to the device to support usb-serial converter/bridge applications (i.e. to tell the device what rate to set its UART t)o. If you are not bridging to a UART, your application should ignore it.  On STM32F1xx @72MHz using ST''s USB library I have achieved ~700kbps (regardless of what the PC sets the baud rate to).  USB is a master-lave communication and relies on the device responding correctly and promptly to requests; it is easy perhaps to get that wrong.

Comment: What target and whose library - or did you write the stack from scratch?  I know you have posted a link in a comment, but that information should be in the question, not in a comment response.

Comment: The PC will poll the device once per millisecond; if the response is a single byte payload, you will restrict the effective data rate to just 1 kbytes/s.  You need to pack all available data at the time of asking into a single frame.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that number was a dummy value that is a holdover from RS232 days, but I might be wrong.

You are correct, the baud number is a dummy value. If you create a CDC/RS232 adapter you would use this to configure your RS232 hardware, in this case it means nothing.

> Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Absolutely! You should be writing chunks of data the same size as your USB endpoint for maximum transfer speed. Depending on the device you are using your stream of single byte writes may be gathered into a single packet before sending but from my experience (and your results) this is unlikely.

Depending on your latency requirements you can stick in a circular buffer and only issue data from it to the USB_Write function when you have ENDPOINT_SZ number of byes. If this results in excessive latency or your interface is not always communicating you may want to implement Nagles algorithm.

> One of my concerns that I have, is that in the old system we had a board in the system dedicated to communications.

The NXP part you mentioned in the comments is without a doubt fast enough to saturate a USB full speed connection.

> In short is this more likely a fundamental system constraint or a software optimization issue?

I would consider this a software design issue rather than an optimisation one, but no, it is unlikely you are fundamentally stuck.

Do take care to figure out exactly what sort of USB connection you are using though, if you are using USB 1.1 you will be limited to 64KB/s, USB 2.0 full speed you will be limited to 512KB/s. If you require higher throughput you should migrate to using a separate bulk endpoint for the data transfer.

I would recommend reading through the USB made simple site to get a good overview of the various USB speeds and their capabilities.

One final issue, vendor CDC libraries are not always the best and implementations of the CDC standard can vary. You can theoretically get more data through a CDC endpoint by using larger endpoints, I have seen this bring host side drivers to their knees though - if you go this route create a custom driver using bulk endpoints.

Try testing your device on multiple systems, you may find you get quite different results between windows and linux. This will help to point the finger at the host end.

And finally, make sure you are doing big buffered reads on the host side, USB will stop transferring data once the host side buffers are full.

Comment: Actually, USB 1.1 handles up about 1.1 MB/s (800 kB/s with a hub adding latency) through CDC, the 64 kB limit applies to full-speed interrupt endpoints only used for polling here. This requires great care in the USB device stack though, often written for flexibility rather than performance, and proper use of hardware features such as multi-frame packet transfers, double-buffered endpoints and DMA as well as tight interrupts and of asynchronously structured code to keep the endpoints armed without missing host polling attempts.

Comment: I must also concur with the assessment of dodgy host CDC drivers, even the traditional Microsoft CDC one has an unfortunate tendency to induce BSoDs. Not to mention the annoying serial mouse detection. Personally I have had good experiences with driver-free USB HID on Windows via GET_REPORT/SET_REPORT requests to do bulk transfers, at least on USB devices not limiting the feature set of the control endpoint. You can achieve same transfer speeds of the same order as CDC this way and with significantly less driver hassle.

Comment: @doynax USB 1.1 can handle more data, but a 64 byte endpoint being polled at 1KHz, as in the case of CDC class can only push 64KB/s.

I spent some time trying to get CDC to use endpoints greater than 64 bytes but to no avail.

+1 for you second comment, completely agree.

Comment: Sort of, but the host stack will continue to poll the bulk endpoint immediately after the first packet before switching to the slower interrupt polling. The trick is to be ready with the data in time. At least that's my recollection, I can't quote chapter and verse from the CDC class specification off-hand.

Comment: @Doynax I just went to double check and you are entirely correct, I have never managed to get that performance out of a CDC connection though and suspect using a custom USB driver/bulk endpoint would be required.

Comment: Since I'm sitting with this right now, I can confirm that theoretically it's higher. The bulk transfers can transfer 64kB/micro frame on USB1.1, but I think it's up to 19 micro frames per second (depending on the host availability). With an nRF52840, I get transfer speeds of about 128kB stable, and 256kB semi-stable. As soon as I start other USB stuff though, I don't have a chance of 256 on Windows :\ Endpoint size 64, transfer size 1280